# Is it possible for one C# dll to raise an event that another C# dll handles?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to raise an event in one .dll that can be handled by another?  If so, what should I be looking at.

EDIT:

I think the two dlls are running in the same process - they are both add-ins to another program.  I'm limited to what I can do with add-ins, hence the need to have this communication.

I thought about writing to a local file and reading it from the other dll, but how would I know when to read it.

Comment: Process or DLL? Please elaborate on your scenario.

Comment: A dll is not a process. You can't raise a .NET event in one process and handle it in another, but you *can* raise it from code in one DLL and handle it with code from another, if they are running in the same process

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's impossible to suggest other techniques without knowing specifics. For all we know, you may not even need events, eg. if you are trying to implement a producer/consumer pair

Comment: You want something like IPC with an event sink or some-such but need more details for sure.

Comment: In case of *WinForms*  (and *event* means *window message*) you can use `SendMessage` or `PostMessage` with a help of *pInvoke*

Comment: if in the same process, it is possible. Otherwise, you need IPC like @LIoyd suggested, or message queue

Comment: So, can I get some example code if in the same process please

Comment: if in the same process than it's trivial - your dll can just expose a class that has an event which your client can subscribe to ? What have you tried ?

Comment: Hi auburg - not tried anything yet as I don't know how to do it, but now I know its possible - how do I expose a class in C#

Comment: @Graham what is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve? Why do you think that you need tow *processes* to solve it? The answer is *completely* different if eg you have a chat application (WCF, Rest, pipes), if you want to process data in parallel (no processes necessary, use PLINQ, Dataflow, Numerics etc) or if you want to synchronize access to a common resource (events, mutexes etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [Interprocess Communication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx)

You probably would like to look on *Pipes*, or look into the [IpcChannel Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.channels.ipc.ipcchannel(v=vs.110).aspx), which may make things even easier. I personally didn't use any of those under `C#` language, but what important, is an idea and technology behind, the rest is an implementation detail.

Comment: Not quite. You *do* need to know the scenario as different technologies fit different scenarios. Eg. there's no need to launch multiple processes to perform parallel processing. WCF on the other hand offers an abstraction on top of IPC (although not a very good one). Redirecting the standard streams is yet another option.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is what "know idea and technology" words mean in my post. Once you know them and obvioulsy your project domain, you are able to make an appropriate choice.